# Why the EOS documentation still says Dawn 4.1?

Tags: smart-contract, dapp

Has the [documentation](https://eosio.github.io/eos/index.html) been updated to 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official developers page with documentation is now at https://developers.eos.io

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have not yet updated to the new version.

You can create it yourself. Follow these guidelines.

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Doxygen-Guidelines

Path and filename do not match in guide. You can do the following: 
In the eos folder, run **doxygen eos.doxygen.in**.